# Create JPanel with component in it

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create JPanel having some JLabels in it, to which I want to pass value by constructor of JPanel.
As below.

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel
 {

 private JLabel lbl;

     public MyPanel(String val)
{
   super();
   lbl=new JLabel(val);
   this.add(lbl);
}
 }
```

And while using this Panel `MyPanel mp=new MyPanel("value");`

But I am not able to see the Label inside the Panel.

What may be the problem?
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, you are trying to add multiple components to your frame without specifying `BorderLayout` poistions.  The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.  It not specified, all component will be added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. Each position can only hold one component. So only the last component you add will be visible.

- You could either set another Layout Manager to the frame,
- or add the components with specified positions like

  ```
  frame.add(new MyPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame add(anotherPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  ```
- Also make sure to call `.pack()` on the frame, so all preferred sizes are respected. Avoid using `.setSize()` if that's what you're doing.

---

**EDIT**

Works for me. Maybe you forgot to pass a String to the constructor. Run this test

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MyPanel("Hello, World!"));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private JLabel lbl;

        public MyPanel(String val) {
            super();
            lbl = new JLabel(val);
            this.add(lbl);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can see blank JPanel without JLabel in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a LayoutManager for the MyPanel

e.g.

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(lbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to `repaint()` or `validate()` your `JPanel` after adding new `JLabel` in it dynamically.

```
lbl=new JLabel(val);
this.add(lbl);
this.validate();
```

or

```
lbl=new JLabel(val);
this.add(lbl);
this.repaint();
```

Also use `setSize(getPreferedSize())` and `setLocation()`:

```
lbl.setSize(lbl.getPreferredSize());
lbl.setLocation(50, 20);
```

Finally you should use proper layout i.e. `BorderLayout` or `GridLayout`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For JPanel the default is BorderLayout, So there is no need to set layout. You shold add the label to content pane.. Try This

{

```
JLabel lb1 = new JLabel(val);
getContentPane().add(val);
```

}

Comment: _"For JPanel the default is BorderLayout"_ - Try `JPanel panel = new JPanel(); System.out.println(panel.getLayout());` See what you get ;)

Comment: Sorry.. Its for JFrame :P